# Does $\text{ACA}_0$ + True Arithmetic prove the well-foundedness of every recursive ordinal?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, foundations, reverse-math, ordinal-analysis

As discussed in [Noah Schweber's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4599997/71829) to [What is the proof-theoretic ordinal of true arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599784/what-is-the-proof-theoretic-ordinal-of-true-arithmetic), it is somewhat ambiguous what “the proof-theoretic ordinal of True Arithmetic” might mean.  In one sense, it is $\omega_1^\text{CK}$, because e.g. True Arithmetic satisfies $\Sigma^0_1$ induction for every notation for a recursive ordinal.  But of course $\Sigma^0_1$ transfinite induction is not the same as full transfinite induction, which can’t even be expressed in the language of first-order arithmetic, so I’d like to ask about a second-order version of this notion.

My question is, which ordinals $\alpha$ can $\text{ACA}_0$ + True Arithmetic prove are well-founded, in the sense that there exists some arithmetically definable well-ordering $R$ with order type $\alpha$ such that $\text{ACA}_0$ + True Arithmetic proves $\operatorname{WO}(R)$?  Where $\operatorname{WO}(R)$ is the $\Pi^1_1$ sentence asserting $R$ is well-ordered, i.e. $R$ satisfies transfinite induction for all sets, not merely for e.g. $\Sigma^0_1$ sets.

Is the answer all recursive ordinals?  If so, how does that square with the work of Feferman and Schutte, who made infinitary deductive systems for ramified second-order arithmetic containing $\text{ACA}_0$, the omega rule, and various comprehension schemes, and found that the proof-theoretic ordinal of the resultant systems is $\Gamma_0$, the Feferman–Schutte ordinal which is recursive?

Answer (score 7):

There is a result of Kreisel (see [1, Theorem 6.7.4,6.7.5]) that for extensions of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ the $\Pi^1_1$ proof-theoretic ordinal (suprema of the order types of provable recursive well-orderings) doesn't change after additions of true $\Sigma^1_1$-sentences. Also note that for infinitely axiomatized theory $T$ its $\Pi^1_1$ proof-theoretic ordinal is the suprema of proof-theoretic ordinals of its finite subtheories. Thus the $\Pi^1_1$  proof-theoretic ordinal of $\mathsf{ACA}_0+\mathsf{Th}(\mathbb{N};0,1,+,\times)$ is $\varepsilon_0$.

[1] Wolfram Pohlers. Proof theory: The first step into impredicativity. Springer Science, 2008.

Comment: Hmm, does $ACA_0$ + the omega rule have a higher $\Pi^1_1$ proof-theoretic ordinal?

Comment: Sure, the closure of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ under $\omega$-rule will have $\omega_1^{\mathit{CK}}$ as its $\Pi^1_1$-ordinal. The point is that unlike all first-order truths, when applied to second-order formulas, $\omega$ rule isn't restricted to $\Sigma^1_1$ conclusions.

Comment: By the way, there is a citation button in the editor. It's not supported on touch devices or I'd edit the answer myself.

Comment: How do you prove that $ACA_0$ + the omega rule can prove that every recursive ordinal is well-founded?

Comment: @Keshav Simply by virtue of the fact that $\omega$-logic proves all true $\Pi^1_1$-sentences (for example, you could read about this in Pohlers textbook that I referred to in the answer).

Comment: Can you tell me what theorem number of Pohler’s book discusses this?  I tried searching for the terms omega rule and omega logic, but nothing came up, unless he uses different terminology.  Also, how does this square is with the infinitary system of ramified analysis that Feferman and Schutte came up with, which incorporates the omega rule but still can only proof the well-foundedness of ordinals less than Gamma_0, much smaller than omega_1^CK?  See pages 17-19 of this Feferman paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2269764

Comment: In Pohlers this is Theorem 5.4.9; to obtain the exact result about the closure of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ under $\omega$-rule additionally we need to show by transfinite induction on $\alpha$ that $\models_\alpha F(\vec{X})$ (in Pohlers notations) implies provability of $\forall \vec{X} F(\vec{X})$ in the closure of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ under $\omega$-rule. I don't remember the exact setup of Feferman's paper (couldn't access it right now), but I am pretty much sure that he should be limiting the iterated applications of $\omega$-rule to the ordinals that already have been justified (autonomous process).